# can I use listener thread send different message to multiframe in wxpython?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, frame

I have a listener thread send message to a frame in wxpython,it work.but now I want to make multiframe,can I use this listener thread send diffrent message to two frame?If it can do this?How should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use pubsub combined with threads for this sort of thing. There's an example in my blog article here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Basically you set up a couple of listeners (one per frame for your example) and then publish messages to those listeners from the threads using one of wx's thread-safe methods.

Comment: thanks.I have alreade made the program by the pubsub.I wonder to konw how to use one thread to send diffrent message two frame,maybe I must use  couple of listeners.

Comment: Yeah. Each frame has it's own unique listener. Then in the thread, you just publish to whichever listener you want to.